Codewars 4 kyu "Most frequently used words in a text" with Python
Write a function that, given a string of text (possibly with punctuation and line-breaks), returns an array of the top-3 most occurring words, in descending order of the number of occurrences.
Assumptions:
A word is a string of letters (A to Z) optionally containing one or more apostrophes (') in ASCII.
Apostrophes can appear at the start, middle or end of a word ('abc, abc', 'abc', ab'c are all valid)
Any other characters (e.g. #, , / , . ...) are not part of a word and should be treated as whitespace.
Matches should be case-insensitive, and the words in the result should be lowercased.
Ties may be broken arbitrarily.
If a text contains fewer than three unique words, then either the top-2 or top-1 words should be returned, or an empty array if a text contains no words.
def top_3_words(text):
    res = {}
    textf = ''.join([char.lower() for char in text if char.isalpha() or char == ' ' or char == "'"]).split(' ') # Create list with the allowed chars in lower case, join it and split it
    for char in textf:
        if char.replace("'", '').isalpha():
            if char in res:
                res[char] += 1
            else:
                res[char] = 1
    return [i for i, j in sorted(res.items(), key=lambda res: res[1], reverse=True)][:3]

The program passes the fixed codewars tests, as far as I know the code is correct, but, there's only a few of the random tests are returning correct, and I don't think I can see the random tests that are being apllied. Does someone understand why this is not working? or is the problem on codewars?

If text is e.g. aa#bb, textf becomes ['aabb'].

Oh right, such a dumb mistake, instead of just continuing to the next iteration I added a space char and now everything went right. Thank you, @MichaelButscher!

You should replace characters that are never part of a word with spaces instead of removing them. Otherwise, you could join two words separated by a special character into a single word.
textf = ''.join(char.lower() if char.isalpha() or char == ' ' or char == "'" 
                   else ' ' for char in text).split(' ')

Note that there's no need to create a list to pass to join; a generator expression can be used instead.
